# Vue js 2.5 does not work in safari under IOS 9

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I’m using [vue js 2.5.16](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js). Mozilla, Chrome browser work perfectly but Safari Browser not working perfectly.

My Environment:

- vue js: 2.5.16
- Mobile: Iphone 5S (System Version: IOS(9.2))
- Mobile Browser: Safari

**Showing This Code**

```
Title: {{dataInfo.sTitle}}
Desc:  {{datainfo.sDesc}}
```

**My complete code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/weui/jquery-weui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/weui/weui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MyCard.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.0.0/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/weui_js/jquery-weui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <title>Business Card</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card_box">
        <div class="top_line">
          <img v-bind:src="dataInfo.sAvatar" />
          <div class="top_right">
            <div class="top_one">
              <span class="name">{{dataInfo.sRealName}}</span>
              <span class="name_e">{{dataInfo.sEnglishName}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="top_two">
              <span class="company">{{dataInfo.sCompanyName}}</span>
              <span class="position">{{dataInfo.sPositionName}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_line">
          <div class="relation">
            <div class="relation_one" v-if="dataInfo.sPhone">
              <img src="img/MyCard/office_phone@3x.png" alt="" />
              <span>({{dataInfo.iZoneNum}}) {{dataInfo.sPhone}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="relation_one" v-if="dataInfo.sWxAccount">
              <img src="img/MyCard/office_wechat@3x.png" alt="" />
              <span>{{dataInfo.sWxAccount}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="relation_one" v-if="dataInfo.sFbAccount">
              <img src="img/MyCard/office_fb@3x.png" alt="" />
              <span>{{dataInfo.sFbAccount}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="relation_one" v-if="dataInfo.sMail">
              <img src="img/MyCard/office_email@3x.png" alt="" />
              <span>{{dataInfo.sMail}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mdrt" v-if="hasMDRT">
            <div class="mdrt_year">{{dataInfo.sMdrt.dtYear}}</div>
            <img src="img/MyCard/mdrt_blue@3x.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card_box" v-if="dataInfo.sDesc">
        <div class="box_title">sDesc</div>
        <div class="summary">{{dataInfo.sDesc}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card_box" v-if="hasCareer">
        <div class="box_title">Experience</div>
        <div class="experience_list" v-for="item in dataInfo.sCareer">
          <div class="experience_company">{{item.sCompany}}</div>
          <div class="experience_bottom">
            <div class="experience_time">{{item.dtEntryTime | time}} - {{item.dtQuitTime | time}}</div>
            <div class="experience_position">{{item.sPosition}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card_box" v-if="hasHonor">
        <div class="box_title">Honor</div>
        <div class="honor_list" v-for="item in dataInfo.sHonor">
          <div class="honor_left">
            <div class="honor_year">{{item.dtYear}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="honor_right">
            <div class="honor_one">{{item.sHonorTitle}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom_icon" align="center">
        <img src="img/default_png_logo@3x.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: '.container',
        data: {
          dataInfo: {},
          hasCareer: false,
          hasHonor: false,
          hasMDRT: false,
        },
      })

      Vue.filter('time', function(value) {
        if(value == 0) return "now";
        let newDate = new Date(parseInt(value) * 1000);
        return newDate.format('yyyy.MM');
      })

      function getInfoData() {
        var query = this.getParameterByName("query");

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: JSON.stringify({
            'query': query
          }),
          contentType: "application/json",
          url: 'https://app.example.com',
          success: function(data) {
            if(data) {
              if(data.msg == "ok") {
                vm.dataInfo = data.data;
                if(data.data.sCareer.length > 0) {
                  vm.hasCareer = true;
                }
                if(data.data.sHonor.length > 0) {
                  vm.hasHonor = true;
                }
                if(data.data.sMdrt.dtYear.length > 0) {
                  vm.hasMDRT = true;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }

      getInfoData();

      function getParameterByName(field, url) {
        var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
        var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
        var string = reg.exec(href);
        return string ? string[1] : null;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**PS:**

I have introduced babel-polyfill and es6-promise, But it still doesn't work! Anyone has met the same problem or could help to explain a little?
Thanks

Comment: Try to get access to Safari's Debug Console. Don't know how to do that on Windows, but if you have a Mac, it should be pretty straight forward. That should probably point you in the right direction. Maybe this isn't related to Vue at all.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal It shows normal under mac, but does not work under IPhone5S in low version of IOS 9 system.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: @dziraf Vue tag cannot be parsed...